# What is the meaning of this wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, solid-state-physics, graphene, tight-binding

In these notes [here](https://uwaterloo.ca/institute-for-quantum-computing/sites/ca.institute-for-quantum-computing/files/uploads/files/lecture-5.pdf) the tight binding model for graphene is worked out.

The tight Binding Hamiltonian is the usual:

$$H=-t\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}(a_{i}^{\dagger}b_{j}+h.c.)$$

where two different sets of creation/annihilation operators are used because there are 2 different sub lattices in graphene (indicated with A and B).

Then it says at the bottom of page 3 that

> It is convenient to write the TB eigenfunctions in the form of a spinor, whose components correspond to the amplitudes on the A and B atoms respectively

So if I understand correctly the wave function is a two component spinor with the first component corresponding to sub lattice A and the second to sub lattice B:

$$\psi=\begin{bmatrix}\psi_{A}(x) \\ \psi_{B}(x)\end{bmatrix} \quad .$$

The problem is that I don't understand the meaning of a wave function like that. In the case of spin for me it makes sense to have a two component wave function:

$$\psi=\begin{bmatrix}\psi_{up}(x) \\ \psi_{down}(x)\end{bmatrix} \quad ,$$ where for example $|\psi_{up}(x)|^2$ gives the probability density of finding the electron at position x with spin up.

But in the previous case what does it mean? Is $|\psi_{A}(x)|^2$ the probability density of finding the electron at x on sub lattice A? I can't make sense of this statement.

Any suggestions on how to interpret that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis here consist of all the lattice sites, which can be label by the position of a unit cell, $x_i$ and the atom in this cell (A or B):
$$
\phi_{i,A}(x), \phi_{i,B}(x)\leftrightarrow \phi_{i,\alpha} (i=A,B).
$$
The arbitrary wave function than can be written es an expansion in this basis:
$$
\psi(x)=\sum_{i,\alpha}c_{i,\alpha}\phi_{i,\alpha} = 
\sum_{i}c_{i,A}\phi_{i,A}(x) + \sum_{i}c_{i,B}\phi_{i,B}(x)=\psi_A(x) + \psi_B(x)
$$
Since the orbitals $\phi_{i,\alpha}$ are localized on the sites, some matrix elements will be non-zero only between $A$ and $B$, while others only between $A$ and $A$ or $B$ and $B$, which makes it convenient to use the matrix notation.

As an instructive example, one could solve a problem of a one-dimensional chain with two identical masses in a unit cell.

Comment: Is $\phi_{i,\alpha}(x)$ a delta function centered on site I belonging to the $\alpha$ sub lattice? @RogerVadim

Comment: @Mathew yes, this is it.